# Odd Size Door Question

Tags: doors

My house is over 100 years old and the exterior basement door is completely falling apart. The problem is that the door is only 68" high and the surrounding walls are all concrete so I can't make the opening any bigger. Any suggestions on how to replace this door?

Comment: That's a rather broad question. You can buy one or you can build one. Make a decision, then come back and ask something more specific, providing enough details about your situation so we can help properly.

Answer (score 3):

Build a door from boards, or from plywood, insulation, more plywood, and boards.

Buy a solid core door (often can be had reasonably at Habitat Re-Store, if you have one of those near you) and cut it down. Be sure it's solid-core (will be heavy) not hollow-core - those don't cut well.

At the high cost/low work/not DIY end of the spectrum, order a custom-made door.